# How to use FileInfo object from Powershell

Tags: powershell, system.io.fileinfo

I am now starting to use PowerShell and after a lot of time using the Unix shells and want to know how to check for the existence of a file or directory.

In Powershell why does `Exist` return false in the following expression?

```
PS H:\> ([System.IO.FileInfo]"C:\").Exists
False
```

And is there a better way to check if a file is a directory than:

```
PS H:\> ([System.IO.FileInfo]"C:\").Mode.StartsWith("d")
True
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Use `Test-Path` instead of `System.IO.FileInfo.Exists`:

```
PS> Test-Path -Path 'C:\'
True
```

You can also use `-PathType` to test whether the location is a file or directory:

```
PS> Test-Path -Path 'C:\' -PathType Container
True

PS> Test-Path -Path 'C:\' -PathType Leaf
False
```

`DirectoryInfo` and `FileInfo` also both define a `PSIsContainer` property:

```
PS> (Get-Item -Path 'C:\').PSIsContainer
True

PS> (Get-Item -Path 'C:\windows\system32\notepad.exe').PSIsContainer
False
```

Answer (score 13):

> In Powershell why does Exist return false in the following expression?
>
> ```
>   PS H:> ([System.IO.FileInfo]"C:\").Exists
> ```

Because there is no file called "C:\" - it's a directory.

Comment: I'm used to Unix where a directory is a file too.

Answer (score 12):

In addition to [Michael's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/636838/how-to-use-fileinfo-object-from-powershell/636864#636864) you could also test using:

```
PS H:> ([System.IO.DirectoryInfo]"C:\").Exists
True
```

Answer (score 10):

```
Help Test-Path

Test-Path Determines whether all elements of a path exist

Test-Path -PathType Leaf C:\test.txt
Test-Path -PathType Container C:\
Test-Path C:\
```

Answer (score 4):

Both of these evaluate to true

```
$(Get-Item "C:\").GetType() -eq [System.IO.DirectoryInfo]
$(Get-Item "C:\test.txt").GetType() -eq [System.IO.FileInfo]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Get-Item` to allow PowerShell to select between `FileInfo` and `DirectoryInfo`. It will throw an exception if the path doesn't resolve to a location.

```
PS> $(Get-Item "C:\").GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     DirectoryInfo                            System.IO.FileSystemInfo
```

I would only use this over `Test-Path` if you will need the `DirectoryInfo` or `FileInfo` entry if it does exist.

Answer (score 0):

I see the best answer above using get-item, but original question used  [System.IO.FileInfo] so I'll pose an answer.

[System.IO.FileInfo]"C:\Users\carsonk" | select *

Above will show most of the available attributes not shown in the default table view.  There are some PS built-in attributes such as PSIsContainer that won't show by select *

PSIsContainer is not available with [System.IO.FileInfo] so

```
If(([System.IO.FileInfo]"C:\Users\carsonk").directory) {$True}
True
```